# RASA : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikipedia'

Tags: wikipedia-api, rasa

I'm learning to use rasa language. To diversify the answers of the goal I decided to use the Wikipedia api. To create my working environment I used anaconda with the following commands:

```
conda create --name rasaWiki python == 3.7.6
conda activate rasaWiki
pip install rasa
pip install wikipedia
```

In the action.py file, when I try to import 'wikipedia', and launch the server with the command: `rasa run actions` I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named wikipedia

However, I can compile other python programs that use the wikipedia package with the python command `python 'nameOfTheFile.py'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I work under windows, I use anaconda prompt 3. When I was running the rasa run actions command, I was in the environment (base). The wikipedia package I had installed is in the rasaWiki environment. So I installed Wikipedia with the command **pip install wikipedia** in the (base) environment, which solved the problem.